Calculation of normalized values for cost-type criteria in the weighted sum model
According to pymcdm WSM is calculated as follows:
$$ A_i^{\text{score}} =\sum_{j=1}^n \bar{x}_{i j} w_j \quad \text{for } i=1,2,3,\ldots ,m$$
Where:

$m$ is the number of alternatives
$n$ is the number of criteria
$w_j$ denotes the weight of each criterion
$\bar{x}_{ij}$ denote the values of the decision options from the normalized decision matrix.

Unlike the example in Wikipedia, pymcdm normalizes the values before calculating the scores. The normalization for profit-type criteria is as follows:
$$r_{i j}=\frac{x_{i j}}{\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_{i j}}$$
The normalization for cost-type criteria is as follows:
$$r_{i j}=\frac{\frac{1}{x_{i j}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{1}{x_{i j}}}$$
Its all well and good for something like $x_{ij} = [1,2,3,4]$:
$$r_{ij}^{\text{cost}} = [0.48, 0.24, 0.16, 0.12]$$
And
$$r_{ij}^{\text{profit}} = [0.1, 0.2,0.3,0.4]$$
However, if I have a cost-type criterion which contains zeroes such as $x_{ij} = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]$ I end up with zeroes in the denominator, and some of the normalized values become undefined. So, mathematically speaking, how are should I handle zeroes when normalizing for cost-type criteria in the weighted sum model?
